# Return memory address of an array using void

Tags: c, pointers

When I try to run the program it crashes, but it prints the numbers.Why is that?

```
void z(int **k)
{
    int i;
    *k=malloc(20*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0;i<20;i++)
        *k[i]=10;

}
int main()
{
    int *k,i;
    z(&k);
    for (i=0;i<20;i++)
    printf("%d\n",k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It happens because you are printing the pointer and not the value where the pointer points to. By the way, free that memory too.

Comment: `*k[i]=10;` --> `(*k)[i]=10;`,  `printf("%d\n",k);` --> `printf("%d\n",k[i]);`

Comment: @Michi I placed an asterisk before k but it still crashes.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you very much.It works now.Why should I place a parenthesis ?

Comment: It is because of the binding priority. `*k[i]` meant `*(k[i])`

Comment: Another way to saying it is "it is due to *operator precedence*." You can look up the table. `[]` has higher precedence than the `*` operator. So to insure the pointer is dereferenced first, you must use parenthesis so the compiler evaluates `(*k)` before applying the array index `[]`. So `(*k)[i]` says *dereference* `k`, then evaluate the array index (offset) `'i'`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in

```
*k[i]=10;
```

By the order of precedence, it should be,

```
(*k)[i] = 10;
```

The subscripting operator has a higher precedence than the indirection operator. See [Operator Prececence Rules.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Also, in the printf in main, you are printing `printf("%d\n",k)`. This will print the base addresses of the array. If you want the value you should use

```
printf("%d\n",k[i]);
```